# Как связать значения двух инпутов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-form

Здравствуйте. Есть форма с двумя инпутами, где можно вводить исключительно цифры. Необходимо, чтобы при вводе данных в одном из инпутов, числовое значение другого менялось пропорционально, исходя из соотношения (допустим 2:1). То-есть если в первом поле ввели `400`, в другом должно появиться `200` и наоборот.

```js
$('.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
  if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="choose-sizes-form">
  <input class="input-field-styles" type="text" placeholder="Width">
  <input class="input-field-styles" type="text" placeholder="Height">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил как пример, тут ещё есть что улучшать. Т.к. методы имеют почти одну и туже структуру, это можно вынести в функцию. Оставляю вам на доработку. Хорошего коддинга!

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

input1.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if(Number.isFinite(value)) {
    input2.value = value / 2;
  } else {
    input2.value = '';
  }
});

input2.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if(Number.isFinite(value)) {
    input1.value = value * 2;
  } else {
    input1.value = '';
  }
});
```

```css
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="choose-sizes-form">
  <input id="input1" data-type="width" class="input-field-styles" type="text" placeholder="Width">
  <input id="input2" data-type="height" class="input-field-styles" type="text" placeholder="Height">
</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, Василий. Будьте добры, подскажите пожалуйста еще такой момент - как полученные значения округлять до целых чисел?

Comment: Вызвать метод `Math.round(число)`